# NextJS npm run build works locally but failing on CI

Tags: next.js, build, yaml

I am trying to setup a CI workflow for my NextJS app with Github Actions. For some reason my `npm run build` command if failing with the CI workflow, but it works locally. I am getting the error `./src/app/components/cards/Leetcode.js Module not found: Can't resolve '../../utils/useLeetcodeData'`. However, this file does in fact exist at the path it is being access from. Furthermore, the command is working on my local machine and not throwing this error.

**here is my .yml file**

```
name: Deploy to Firebase

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    name: Build and Deploy to Firebase
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    steps:
      - name: Checkout Repo
        uses: actions/checkout@v4.1.1
      - name: Debug Information
        run: |
          ls -R # List all files in the repository
          ls -R ./src # List files in the src directory
          ls -R ./src/app/utils # List files in the utils directory
      - name: Use Node.js 18
        uses: actions/setup-node@v4.0.1
        with:
          node-version: 18
      - name: Install Dependencies
        run: npm ci
      - name: Build
        run: npm run build
      - name: Deploy to Firebase
        uses: w9jds/firebase-action@v13.1.0
        with:
          args: deploy --only hosting
        env:
          FIREBASE_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.FIREBASE_TOKEN }}
```

note I have added the **Debug Information** step to try and verify the file's existence and paths, and from the output I can see that it does in fact according to .

```
./src/app/components/cards:
[... other files]
Leetcode.js <--- file that is importing the module

./src/app/utils:
[... other files]
useLeetCodeData.js <--- file with module
```

**paths**

- and this file is being imported by a React component located at `src/app/component/cards/Leetcode`. The import line is `import useLeetCodeData from '../../utils/useLeetcodeData'`
- the file itself is located at `src/app/utils/useLeetCodeData.js`
  (again, this is all working locally regardless)

What could be causing this issue?